# A circular dependency issue because of imports

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory, factories

What do I have now:

- an abstract class (for ex. AbstractEntity);
- a factory that produces Entities;
- many different types of entities, that extends Entity;

and everything was good enough **but** was added:

- an entity that can contain a list of entities;

In my code it looks like this:

```
// abstract/entity.ts
export abstract class AbstractEntity {
  readonly id: IdKey; //
}
```

```
// entities/concrete-entity.ts
export class ConcreteEntity extends Entity {
  readonly type = 'concrete type';
}

// entities/concrete-entity2.ts
export class ConcreteEntity2 extends Entity {
  readonly type = 'concrete type2';
}
```

```
// abstract/factory.ts
export abstract class EntityFactory {
  static create(creationCase): Entity | null {
    if (someCase === creationCase) { return new ConcreteEntity(); }
    if (otherCase === creationCase) { return new ConcreteEntity2(); }
    if (containerCase === creationCase) { return new ContainerEntity(); }
    
    return null;
  }

  static createFromArray(creationCases): Entity[] {
    return creationCases.map(this.create);
  }
}
```

and my splinter:

```
// entities/container-entity.ts
export class ContainerEntity extends Entity {
  readonly type = 'container';
  readonly entities: Entity[] = EntityFactory.createFromArray(creationCases);
}
```

and right here I have a warning about a circular dependency because my

- factory imports ContainerEntity
- my ContainerEntity imports factory

Comment: Could you provide examples with imports? Also, I don't see where EntityFactory uses ContainerEntity.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, in my EntityFactory must be a statement that creates a ContainerEntity. I'll add it right now, thank you.

And about imports:

in EntityFactory I have `import {ContainerEntity} from '../enitites';`
in EntityContainer I have `import {ContainerFactory} from '../abstract';`

Comment: My instict: The factory needs to know about the concretions, but the concretions do not need to know about the factory.  But I think I'm missing something here without knowing what `creationCases` is.  `ContainerEntity` can contain entities of the other types?  And it creates them itself, rather than receiving instantiated objects?